# how to change spelling to make a silent e sound

Tags: spelling, names, phonetics

My name is June and I am Basque (North of Spain). My name is pronounced almost like in English except for that the final e is not silent.

How do a write my name phonetics to show people how to pronounce it? Also, is there any way to change the spelling do people can read it correctly? Many people don't have knowledge of phonetics.

Comment: Without phonetics, as an English reader I would know how to pronounce it when spelled **Juna**. Alternatively just accept the way that others pronounce it - in other cases names do not anglicise very well. Another solution, as this is about speech, is to introduce yourself: "Hallo, I am June" pronounced the way you would like it to be said. I would favour that, as it is worse to have your name written incorrectly, than spoken incorrectly, and this would be a mistake you cause yourself.

Comment: Alternatively, if the 'e' is pronounced 'eh', you could add an acute accent (like the French _café_). You would still find that not all English speakers read it correctly, though.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The "e" at the end is pronunced like the "e" for elephant. I had a look online and Juna will sound different to my name. Kate, it doesn't have an acute accent at the end. That would make things easier!

Comment: E is pronounced like the first or second "e" in elephant?

Comment: If you start writing your own name incorrectly that's only going to make matters worse, because if it gets copied and spread it won't be possible to put it right. But if people *say* your name wrongly, you can immediately correct them by saying: "My name is June."

Comment: The first e for elephant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with a lot of immigrants to the US and I have seen some people who needed to spell their names phonetically add an H in this kind of situation, so that it would be spelled Juneh.